# Elmah is only logging 15 Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, error-handling, elmah

I've just starting looking at a site in place at work. They're using Elmah to log errors.

It seems to be logging fine, but in the web interface, when I tell Elmah to show me 100 errors per page, it only shows the most recent 15.

Then when I click on "Download Log" I only get shown 15 errors in the CSV.

Anyone know how I can configure it to keep all the errors?

Or can someone point me to some docs on how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

-Evan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there is no database configured to log errors to.

By default it only logs the last **15** errors to memory if it has no where to write it to...

Comment: Ah so it must have no where to write. Do you know where I set where it writes?

Comment: This is the link I learned from.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/errorloggingmodulesandhandlers.aspx

Comment: Thanks ggonsalv!

Specifically:
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/ElmahLogs" />
</elmah>

Comment: Things seem to have changed. On my development machine, I can see more than 15 errors when logging to memory. However, in a release build, I only see the last 15 errors.